# how do I update entity object passed from another class?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

This is my query where I'm returning an `IEnumerable<CreditCardTransaction>` to iterate through.

```
  public partial class CreditCardTransaction
  {

    public static IEnumerable<CreditCardTransaction> GetUnprocessedTransactions()
    {
      try
      {
        using (var context = new SuburbanEntities())
        {
          return from trans in context.CreditCardTransactions
                 where trans.IsPublished == false
                 select trans;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Logging.Log("An error occurred.", "GetUnprocessedTransactions",Apps.ServicesConfig, ex);
        return null;
      }
    }

  }
```

This is where I am modifying those transactions once I have processed them:

```
public void ProcessFile()
{
  try
  {
    _client = new TruckServiceClient();
    _globalSetting = new GlobalSetting();

    var unprocesstransactions = CreditCardTransaction.GetUnprocessedTransactions();
    foreach (var creditCardTransaction in unprocesstransactions)
    {
      creditCardTransaction.IsPublished = ProcessTransaction(creditCardTransaction);
    }     
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logging.Log("An error occurred.", "ProcessCreditCardTransactions.ProcessFile", Apps.RemoteServices, ex);
  }
}
```

I am modifying the transactions here:

```
creditCardTransaction.IsPublished = ProcessTransaction(creditCardTransaction);
```

But once I have saved them, can I update the entity directly or do I need to create another method where I pass this information back in?

Comment: I don't have access to the context from this class. I guess that answers my question then? If I don't have access to the context, I can't save it without creating a new method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you don't have access to the context. Here you have some examples how to do:
https://github.com/geersch/EntityFrameworkObjectContext

If you're developing Asp.Net app, you'll have some drawbacks illustreted in this article:
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-ASP-NET-applications.aspx#managing-objectcontext-instantiation